# What does the 'sheen' slider of the Principled shader do behind the scenes?

Tags: shaders

I'm trying to create a unified shader setup between a bunch of different render engines for exporting models. 
I've been attempting to recreate the 'sheen' effect from the principled shader using commonly available nodes such as layer weight but I've been unable to replicate it 1:1.

Does anyone know exactly what the sheen effect does?

Comment: Here: https://schuttejoe.github.io/post/disneybsdf/ 

I'm not an expert nor anybody in matter of shaders "insides" but it looks like it's Fresnel (sheen) multiplied by extracted color data from base color (sheenTint). I think ;)

Comment: Sheen uses a different algorithm in EEVEE than in Cycles. I think it is physically accurate in Cycles (like the velvet shader), but in EEVEE,[The Sheen Layer is a crude approximation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/render/eevee/materials/nodes_support.html)